# Cannot convert value of type 'addItem.Product' to expected argument type 'productsCollectionViewCell.Product'

Tags: swift, xcode

I was working on a project that would make a collection view. My collection view class is `productsCollectionViewCell`, and `struct` is `Product`. However I get the error
`Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'productsCollectionViewCell'`. I tried removing the `as!`, but it didn't work. What's the ifx to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as!` does a force cast to the type `productsCollectionViewCell` and returns a non-Optional. It will crash the program if it fails.

You probably are looking for `as?` which returns an Optional, which is required by `guard let` to do an Optional binding.

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? productsCollectionViewCell else {
```

---

Other notes:

- In Swift, normally types are capitalized and variables/properties are lowercased, so `productsCollectionViewCell` should probably be `ProductsCollectionViewCell`.
- You may have a typo on the next line -- do you mean `products` instead of `Product` (eg the variable instead of the type)?:

```
cell.setup(with: products[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: So if I use `as?` instead of `as!`, it does fix the problem, but I get another error `Type 'addItem.Product' has no member 'subscript'` on `cell.setup(with: Product[indexPath.row])` (I've also edited the post for clarity). I believe its correct to use `as?`, so how do I fix the other error? I also didn't know that properties are generally capitalized, I will keep that in mind from now!

Comment: Read my whole answer -- it address the other error as well. Also, properties are *not* generally capitalized -- the opposite. Types are capitalized, variables and properties are lowercased.

Comment: I'm not too sure because I am a beginner but it is supposed to be `Product` only since that's my `struct`, no? I get the error `Cannot convert value of type 'addItem.Product' to expected argument type 'productsCollectionViewCell.Product'` when I use products

Comment: If you're getting that error, that's related to code that you haven't shown in your question -- I don't know what type `products` is or what type `setup(with:)` takes. Generally, since you used `products.count` above, the assumption would be that you'd setup from the same array. You would never use the type `Product` with a subscript, though. It sounds like you've defined `struct Product` in multiple places in your project and now they're conflicting. You should *probably* just have one definition of `Product`, I'd guess. Do a search for `Product` and see how many definitions there are.

Comment: If you have trouble resolving this, please add the code for the declaration of `products`, the definition of `setup(with:)` and any `struct Product` that you find to your question.